# Excel: Index match if date matches month?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two excel sheets:

Data:

```
Column A         Column E

01/01/2017      Supplier 1
05/01/2017      Supplier 2
05/01/2017      Supplier 1
```

Sheet 2:

I am trying to look up the supplier where the month of the date in column A matches the month number in cell F11.

```
F11 = 1

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A:$I,SMALL(IF(MONTH(Data!A:A)=$F$11,ROW(Data!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),5)),"",INDEX(Data!$A:$I,SMALL(IF(MONTH(Data!A:A)=$F$11,ROW(Data!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1)),5))
```

For some reason this doesn't work and i get no result.

I also need to only list each supplier name the once, unique values. But i believe my formula gives me the same result twice.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Your formula **(array entered)** correctly retrieves suppliers, but does not remove duplicates.

Comment: Whether or not it provides "the same result twice" depends on the implementation in which you fill your formula.  I just tested your formula and it works fine when entered in the first row.  However, I would suggest marrying your `INDEX` with a `MATCH` to make it less ambiguous.  **Needs more information on the implementation**

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this with a pivot table?

Just drag the date field into the columns box, then right-click, choose 'Group' and choose 'months'. Then drag the supplier field underneath it and you should get a list of all unique suppliers by month.

Edit:

Example below.

[image: example of pivot table]